# Simple-Coil-less-AM-receiver- how to make for 650kHz (BBC from Poland)

Tags: signal

Can enyone help to make it for 650kHz (600-700kHz) for BBC reception from Poland ?
After making it does not receive any station.
What`s wrong ?
http://www.next.gr/inside-circuits/Simple-Coil-less-AM-receiver-l6022.html

Comment: You'll need a good antenna.

Answer (score 5):

Any number of things could be wrong, but there are some very basic things to check on, if you feel the circuit is assembled correctly.

1- are you sure the battery you're using isn't dead? Often times batteries can show a fair voltage when checked open-circuit with a DVM, but then when put under load they have almost no voltage. If you have a new battery, this shouldn't be a concern.

2- any time you have a radio circuit, you have to make sure you have an adequate antenna. For low frequency AM you shouldn't need much, a meter or two of wire should do it, but not necessarily if you are in a basement or inside a metal sided building.

3- with a circuit like that, you probably aren't going to be able to drive a regular speaker low-impedance. Headphones are more likely to work.

Comment: High-impedance headphones (not the Walkman variety) or a crystal earpiece should work.

Answer (score 0):

By my interpretation of the circuit, the two pots will affect both the frequency and feedback gain of what is essentially a damped oscillator circuit; both pots will affect both the frequency and the loop gain, but in different ways, so that holding frequency while adjusting loop gain or vice versa will require tweaking both pots.  Optimal signal sensitivity will be achieved when the loop gain is just short of unity, and will fall to nothing if the loop gain gets to unity or above.

The circuit could probably be made much more useful by adding an indicator to show when the output of the amplifier exceeds 7 volts or so, a circumstance which would occur when the loop gain is too high.  If one had such an indicator, one could use one pot to adjust the frequency while one used the other to hold the loop gain just short of the unity point.  Moving the frequency pot in one direction will increase gain; moving it in the other will decrease it.  One could thus search frequencies in the direction which would increase gain, and 'back off' on the gain pot every time the indicator showed that the gain had gotten too high.